# Blazor page with child component: How can I pass current HTML table row index or Vairable from the row @onclick method button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor page with a child component(displays addresses).  The child component displays a table and the last column displays a button with @oncclick to execute a method (ie: UpdateAddress(??)).   When clicking the button, I need to pass in the row index the button was created on or Entid variable from the row into the @onclick method.   How can I get either of those values to pass to the method?  I know normally you would use a href with the button but the child component does not use a @page link.   Thanks

```
             @for (int i = 0; i < Arae.EntAddModelsList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" checked="@Arae.EntAddModelsList[i].Prim" onclick="return false" class="text-success"></td>
                        <td>@Arae.EntAddModelsList[i].Label</td>  
                        <td>@Arae.EntAddModelsList[i].Add1</td>
                        <td>@Arae.EntAddModelsList[i].EffBegDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                        <a id="@i" class="btn btn-primary table-btn" @onclick="@(() => UpdateAddress(i))">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, you must define a local varaible in your loop like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Arae.EntAddModelsList.Count(); i++)
   {
       var local = i;
   }
```

And use it instead of i in the lambda expression;

As for your question:

define your anchor element like this:

```
<a href="" id="@i" class="btn btn-primary table-btn" @onclick="@(() => 
                                              UpdateAddress(local))">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
 </a>
```

And in the `@code` block add the following:

```
private Task UpdateAddress(int i)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid using an array:

Use a @key on each row.

Note: I did not know the type of EntAddModelsList so I used object. Change this to the item type.

```
@foreach (var entAddModel in Arae.EntAddModelsList)
{
<tr @key="entAddModel"> 
    ...
    <td>@entAddModel.Label</td> // more concise than Arae.EntAddModelsList[i].Label
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-primary table-btn" @onclick="@(() => UpdateAddress(entAddModel))">
        <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    </button>
</tr>
}

@code {
    async ValueTask UpdateAddress(object entAddModel) // Change object to the correct type
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Side Note:

To bind to a checkbox use something like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" checked @bind="entAddModel.Prim">
```

Comment: I would vote twice if I could because you swapped the anchor for a button ✔